# OpenLayers GeoJson reprojection

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson, projection

I hot stack with reprojection of **GeoJson**
I have ***GeoJson*** object loaded by ajax from server
Object has CRS set to **EPSG:2180**
I want to overlay it on **OpenStreet Map** that has CRS **EPSG:3857**

```
var buildingsFeatures = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures($buildings, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:2180',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
```

**$building** is ***GeoJson FeatureCollection*** object and above code is as per OpenLayers documentation but coordinates are not changed.

I hit a wall with it :(

Answer (score 0):

Things to do to make it working:

- get proj4.js from https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/releases
- define EPSG:2180 either inside your code or in proj4-defs.js file as

> proj4.defs([
>       [
>           'EPSG:2180',
>           '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs'
>       ]
>   ]);

and that's all.